# style fontWeight and fontStyle react-native cannot work together

Tags: ios, react-native

why fontWeight and fontStyle cannot work together in react-native on ios?

```
<Text style={{fontSize: 20, fontFamily: 'Century', fontWeight: '900', fontStyle: 'oblique'}}>ASD</Text>
```

the output like "normal italic".
my expect is bold italic

Answer (score 1):

Use `italic` instead of `oblique` for your `fontStyle`. In react native, oblique is not a valid `fontStyle`.

`fontStyle` is limited to two values `normal` and `italic`. You can see more in the [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/next/text-style-props.html#fontstyle).

Comment: using italic it's the same output like normal italic